# Is it possible to zoom dynamic content with silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I am new one with Silverlight and I am interested in how to zoom dynamic content.
For instance i have canvas and several listboxes and i want to zoom it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Every visual element within Silverlight has a number of different ways you can transform it. Scaling can be applied by adding a ScaleTransform object othe an objects renderTransform.

```
<Canvas>
     <Canvas.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
     </Canvas.RenderTransform>
     <ListBox />
</Canvas>
```

The above XAML will scale everything inside the Canvas (in this case just the ListBox). The ListBox will continue to behave just like a ListBox.